# Is it possible to have multiple wildcard subdomain azure application gateway listeners?

Tags: azure, dns, wildcard-subdomain, azure-application-gateway

I'd like to host multiple domains and handle subdomain wildcards. Is this possible to do with a single app gateway?

For example, here are the listeners I am attempting to setup:

- app.example1.com -> poolA
- app.example2.com -> poolA
- *.example1.com -> poolB
- *.example2.com -> poolB

The problem that I'm running into is when I go to add the second app gateway listener I get an error indicating that it can only have 1 "basic" type. If I attempt to create a second listener with a * I get an error indicating that it's an invalid host value. Is there a better way to configure this type of routing that maybe I'm missing?

[image: basic listener]

[image: multi site listener with wildcard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can host multi-sites and subdomain wildcards in a single application gateway. Take a look at the [Application Gateway multiple site hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview). But it's just a preview version, and this feature is in preview and is available only for Standard_v2 and WAF_v2 SKU of Application Gateway. It notes:

> This feature is currently available only through Azure PowerShell and
> Azure CLI. Portal support is coming soon. Please note that since
> portal support is not fully available if you are using only the
> HostNames parameter, the listener will appear as a Basic listener in
> the portal and the Host name column of the listener list view will not
> show the host names that are configured.

The CLI command [`az network application-gateway http-listener create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/http-listener?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_http_listener_create) works on the subdomain wildcards with parameter `host-names`.